# Using lapply instead of repeating code

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I would like to know how to use lapply and/or for loops to have more concise code.

This is what I currently have and it works.

```
MLFreq <- MLlyrics %>%
unnest_tokens(word, line) %>%
anti_join(stop_words) %>%
ungroup() %>%
count(word)
MLpct <- sum(albumList2$MLlyrics$n) / sum(MLFreq$n)

ViewFreq <- ViewLyrics %>%
unnest_tokens(word, line) %>%
anti_join(stop_words) %>%
ungroup() %>%
count(word)
Viewpct <- sum(albumList2$ViewLyrics$n) / sum(ViewFreq$n)

#... repeating 6 times with different data frames
```

I've been trying

```
Freq <- lapply(albumList2, function(df){
df %>% unnest_tokens(word, line) %>%
anti_join(stop_words) %>%
ungroup()%>%
count(word) %>%
sum(albumList2$df$n) / sum(df$n)
})
```

and

```
for (i in 1:length(albumList2)) {
unnest_tokens(word, line) %>%
anti_join(stop_words) %>%
ungroup()%>%
count(word) %>%
print(sum(albumList2$i$n) / sum(i$n))
}
```

but the lapply brings

```
Error in check_input(x) : Input must be a character vector of any length or 
a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

and the for loop brings

```
no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class 
"function"
```

For reference albumList2 contains a list of data frames (MLlyrics, ViewLyrics, etc...)

I was originally going to leave it as is but just read something along the lines of "If you use the same code 3 times, loop over it"

Comment: Can you give an example dataset please? I would like to help, but it would be nice to have some dummy data using `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the lapply example is that the list that you are looping over is a nested list instead of single list.

Also, references of the kind: `sum(albumList2$df$n) / sum(df$n)` & `print(sum(albumList2$i$n) / sum(i$n))` would not work.

`i` is just a number ranging from 1 to length(albumList2). Saying you want 1$n or albumList2$1$n does not make sense.

You should read about indexing in lists and nested lists [here](https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/list) and [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list). Please add some dummy data that everyone can test and help you better.